# Ruby split by comma absorbing trailing space

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I need to split a string into two variables. For example, the following would work fine:

```
first,second = "red,blue".split(',')
```

I would like to split user input, which might have an optional space after the comma. How do I write it so a space after the comma is absorbed? I need to correctly handle all these possibilities:

```
"red,blue"        # first="red" second="blue"
"red, blue"       # first="red" second="blue"
"red,dark blue"   # first="red" second="dark blue"
"red, light blue" # first="red" second="light blue"
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just trim the resulting entries. The way you do this depends on whether you want to support exactly one space after the comma, or whether you want to remove all leading whitespace (and maybe trailing whitespace too). If your goal is to get words, like it looks like in your sample, you should just remove all surrounding whitespace.

```
first,second = "red, blue".split(',').map(&:strip)
```

Answer (score 11):

There is no regexp in your code - you split using a string, which makes a difference.
`"red,blue".split(/\s*,\s*/)` should work as you expect.

Comment: While it's not an example mentioned in the question, this won't work for `"red ,blue"`.

Comment: I know there's no regex in my example, my example was to show code that does what I want but doesn't handle all the variations. I tried many regex variations but they didn't catch all.

Comment: Just put another \s in front of the comma: `"red ,blue".split(/\s*,\s*/)`

Comment: @AndrewMarshall A trailing space is the user's variation. A space preceding a comma is the user's obvious mistake. It's fine to not work for the case you mention.

Comment: @sawa I was mentioning it because it's a difference between the way the other two answers behave.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.split(/, */)
```

This is a regular expression that works with or without a space after the comma.