# Read a file with ruby to two variables directly

Tags: ruby

with [How can I read a file with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157207/how-can-i-read-a-file-with-ruby), read file then print it one line by one line.

But my request is different.

I have a txt file with similar content of thousand lines.

```
ABC 123
XYZ 234
```

So with below code, I can print the whole lines.

```
File.open("input.txt", "r") do |infile|
    while (line = infile.gets)
        puts "#{counter}: #{line}"
        counter = counter + 1
    end
end
```

But I need something to assign column1 to A, and column2 to B directly:

```
File.open("input.txt", "r").each_line do |A B|
        puts "#{A} has the value of #{B}"
end
```

How can I do that.

Generally, I need a ruby function as in bash scripting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read A B 
do
  echo "$A has the value of $B"
done < input.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't need to store the values for future reference you can pretty easily split the line at the space and use it as an array to pull both variables. Also, if you iterate with each line it will save you the possibilities of minor errors in the loops, but you can always replace it with a loop.

```
File.open("my/file/path", "r").each_line do |line|
  vars=line.split(" ")
  puts "#{vars[0]} has the value of #{vars[1]}"
end
```

Comment: Split function is good idea, are there any ` field separator` such as whitespace I can use ? otherwise, it may not already split to vars[1].

Comment: I still prefer it can assign to two variables directly with splitted by `whitespace`, not sure ruby has this function already or not.

Comment: if you want 2 variables you could do it this way instead  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576407/ruby-split-by-comma-absorbing-trailing-space

Comment: seems line.split() accpet space as whitespace already. I add more spaces and tabs, no impact and get same result.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```
File.open("my/file/path", "r").each_line do |line|
  var1, var2 =line.split(" ")
end
```

If not then please look at using CSV lib:
http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-csv-library-part/

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
fname = 'tmp'
str =<<_
cat 1
dog 2
pig 3
_

File.write(fname, str)

IO.foreach(fname) {|l| puts "%s has the value of %s" % l.split }
cat has the value of 1
dog has the value of 2
pig has the value of 3
```